# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'proform_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web-frameworks, laravel-migrations

After php artisan migrate:fresh I get error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'proform_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `proforms` add constraint `proforms_proform_id_foreign` foreign key (`proform_id`) references `proforms` (`id`) on delete cascade)

This is migration which generates error:
2020_08_08_093303_create_dynamic_field.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDynamicField extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dynamic_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('id_pozycji')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('PKWIU')->nullable();
            $table->integer('quantity')->nullable();
            $table->integer('unit')->nullable();
            $table->integer('netunit')->nullable();
            $table->integer('nettotal')->nullable();
            $table->integer('VATrate')->nullable();
            $table->integer('grossunit')->nullable();
            $table->integer('grosstotal')->nullable();
            $table->integer('proform_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->time('deleted_at')->nullable();
        });

        Schema::table('proforms', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('proform_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('proforms')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');            
        });





    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dynamic_fields');
    }
}
```

This is migration asociated with it:
2020_07_29_101958_proforms.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Proforms extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('proforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('proformnumber')->nullable();
            $table->date('proformdate')->nullable();
            $table->date('selldate')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('form_id')->unsigned()->nullable();                        
            $table->integer('currency_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('paymentmethod')->nullable();
            $table->date('paymentdate')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->string('comments')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();            
            $table->string('autonumber')->nullable();
            $table->integer('automonth')->nullable();
            $table->integer('autoyear')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('PKWIU')->nullable();
            $table->integer('quantity')->nullable();
            $table->integer('unit')->nullable();
            $table->integer('netunit')->nullable();
            $table->integer('nettotal')->nullable();
            $table->integer('VATrate')->nullable();
            $table->integer('grossunit')->nullable();
            $table->integer('grosstotal')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->time('deleted_at')->nullable();
        });
        
        Schema::table('proforms', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->foreign('form_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('forms')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');                
    

            $table->foreign('currency_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('currencys')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            
            
            
            
            
            
        });
```

Comment: Your `proforms` tables indeed doesn't have a `proform_id`... Why are you trying to set `FK` (`proform_id`) to the same table (`proforms`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks odd to me:

```
Schema::table('proforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('proform_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('proforms')
          ->onDelete('cascade');            
});
```

It looks like you are trying to add a foreign key with a reference to it's own table.

There is no `proform_id` on the `proforms` table. This statement needs to be run on the `dynamic_fields` table.

```
Schema::table('dynamic_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('proform_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('proforms')
          ->onDelete('cascade');            
});
```

Comment: After that change I've got other error:
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `dynamic_fields` add constraint `dynamic_fields_proform_id_foreign` foreign key (`proform_id`) references `proforms` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: @Piotr, foreign key should be unsigned, 
change `$table->integer('proform_id')->nullable();` to `$table->integer('proform_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`

Comment: Make sure that the two tables use the same database engine (i.e InnoDB ) and that the `proforms`.`id` column and `dynamic_fields`.`proform_id` are both using the same data type (i.e. both are `integer` or `bigInteger`)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding foreignId instead of just foreign like so:

```
Schema::table('proforms', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreignId('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).